# The file is renamed with batch file but it won't stop

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I need to rename all files in a folder by adding "BV" in front of the files name. My code is functioning but the problem appears when the total amount of file in that folder is more than ca. 200 files. It will rename all files to this: "BV_BV_BV..." and it won't stop.

Here is my code:

```
@echo off & setlocal

ECHO Moechten Sie das wirklich tun? (Bereits vorhandene Bildverzeichnisse werden geloescht 
ECHO und in den Dateinamen wird AWK2 hinzugefuegt) (j / n)
SET /p wahl=
if '%wahl%' == 'n' goto Nein
if '%wahl%' == 'j' goto Ja

:Ja
ECHO on

FOR %%I IN (*.bmp) DO ren "%%I" BV_"%%~nI".bmp

pause
```

I am not sure how I can make the batch file stop after all files have been renamed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you read the line just above the `SET /p` @Gerhard, I'm going to suggest `AWK2` instead, `Do you really want to do that? (Pre-existing image directories will be deleted and AWK2 added to the filename) (y / n)`

Comment: **1.** `for` buffers some file names, renames them and then read the next ones, so files might become renamed multiple times; to avoid that, use `for /F "delims= eol=|" %%I in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "*.bmp"') do ren "%%I" "BV_%%~nxI"`; this method first gets the whole list of files before any of them becomes renamed. **2.** `set "wahl=" & set /P wahl=""`. **3.** `if /I "%wahl%"=="n" goto nein`. **4.** Where is `:nein`? **5.** Instead of `set /P` consider to use [`choice`](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) for such yes/no prompts…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to rename all files once, with the prefix of `BV_` as per your example in the `for` loop. Notice, I used `choice` instead of `set /p`

```
@echo off & setlocal

ECHO Moechten Sie das wirklich tun? (Bereits vorhandene Bildverzeichnisse werden geloescht 
ECHO und in den Dateinamen wird AWK2 hinzugefuegt) (j / n)
choice /c jn /m "wahl"
goto opt%errorlevel%

:opt1
for /f "delims=" %%I IN ('dir /b /a-d *.bmp ^| findstr /v /b "BV_"') do ren "%%~I" "BV_%%~I"
goto :eof
:opt2
echo do what ever you need to do here.
```